# MySQL Query inside nested if condition doesn't seem to work on online hosting?

Tags: php, mysql

While sending MySQL query from nested if condition I am getting redirected to the same page and the query doesn't seem to work.

This is my nested query.

Here I'm receiving string input from a form and want to send this to the database. But this query is not working on cpanel hosting. While this works on local XAMPP stack.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_pending'])) {

  $pendingParticulars = $_POST['gr_particulars'];
  $pendingUnit        = $_POST['gr_unit'];
  $pendingRate        = $_POST['gr_rate'];
  $pendingReceived    = $_POST['gr_updateReceived'];
  $poNumber           = $_POST['gr_number'];
  $pendingAmount      = $pendingRate * $pendingReceived;

  $requiredUnit       =  $pendingUnit - $pendingReceived;
  $excess             =  $pendingReceived - $pendingUnit;
  $excess             =  max(0, $excess);
  $requiredUnit       =  max(0, $requiredUnit);
  $pendingShortage    =  $pendingUnit - $pendingReceived;
  if ($requiredUnit   == 0) {

    $submitGoodsQuery = "INSERT INTO goods_received (po_number, particulars, unit, actual_received, shortage, accepted, rejected, pending, rate, amount, status) VALUES ('$poNumber', '$pendingParticulars', '$pendingUnit', '$pendingReceived', '$requiredUnit', '$pendingReceived', 0, '$requiredUnit', '$pendingRate', '$pendingAmount', 'Received')";

    $submitGoodsResult = mysqli_query($connection, $submitGoodsQuery);

    if ($submitGoodsResult) {

      $updateGoodsPO = mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM pending_goods WHERE po_number = '$poNumber' ");

      header("Refresh:0");

    } 

  } elseif ($requiredUnit > 0) {

    $submitGoodsQuery = "INSERT INTO goods_received (po_number, particulars, unit, actual_received, shortage, excess, accepted, rejected, pending, rate, amount, status) VALUES ('$poNumber', '$pendingParticulars', '$pendingUnit', '$pendingReceived', '$pendingShortage', 0, '$pendingReceived', 0, '$requiredUnit', '$pendingRate', '$pendingAmount', 'Received')";

    $submitGoodsResult = mysqli_query($connection, $submitGoodsQuery);

    if ($submitGoodsResult) {

      $newPoNumberQue   = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT pending_number FROM pending_goods WHERE po_number =  '$poNumber' AND po_particulars = '$pendingParticulars' ORDER BY serial_number DESC ");

      $pendingCount     = mysqli_num_rows($newPoNumberQue);

      $updateGoodsPO = mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM pending_goods WHERE po_number = '$poNumber' ");

      $insertNewVals = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO pending_goods (po_number, po_particulars, po_quantity, po_RateWithGst, goods_status) VALUES ('$poNumber', '$pendingParticulars', '$pendingShortage', '$pendingRate', 'Partially') ");


      header("Refresh:0");

    }
  }
 } // End submit pending
} // End get pending
```

Comment: Note: you’re directly using values from the user in your SQL queries. *This is dangerous* and can easily lead to SQL injection and/or broken queries. Change the code to use parameters/prepared statements. Otherwise there will be problems.

Comment: In what way is it "not working".

Comment: On running this query I get redirected to the same page. as I'm using header redirect function. But the query does not execute.

Comment: I would suggest you turn on [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and replace the `header("Refresh:0");` with `exit;` and see what errors get reported.

Comment: Where have you declared the connection?